# Counting unique strings across multiple groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's my data:

```
db = data.frame(plot = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
                         'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b',
                         'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'),
                spp = c('sp1', 'sp1', 'sp2', 'sp1', 'sp3',
                        'sp1', 'sp1', 'sp2', 'sp4', 'sp4',
                        'sp1', 'sp2', 'sp5', 'sp6', 'sp7'))
```

What I'm trying to do is find, for each `plot`, the number of unique strings that occur only at each plot **when compared to all others**.

I was using

```
db_sum <- db %>%
     group_by(plot) %>%
     summarise(n_unique = n_distinct(across(spp)))
```

but that returns the number of unique strings in each plot, and not the number of unique strings in each plot when compared to all others.

For example, the aforementioned function returns a = 3, b = 3, c = 5, but what I want is a = 1, b = 1, c = 3 (that is, a has one `spp` that is not shared by the others `plot` and the same goes for the others)

How can I proceed?

Comment: `db |> distinct() |> add_count(spp) |> filter(n == 1) |> count(plot)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `base R` with `table`

```
table(subset(unique(db), spp %in% names(which(table(spp) == 1)))$plot)

a b c 
1 1 3
```